# To notch internal bottom corners of steps

Tags: router, circular-saw

Is there a power tool that will notch the bottom corner of already existing stairs? It's an old wooden staircase that we are putting laminate flooring on. For a neater look, we intend to make a continuous groove and slide the boards in. Any ideas or tools I can use

Comment: Hi, if bottom corner is where stair top meets riser I don't think this is possible with router. I can think of 2 methods, but not quick or easy. This is not normally done maybe b/c of how hard it will be!

Comment: How thick is flooring? What is plan to hide lamination at front edge?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. From the solutions I can envisage while this is possible I don't think it's a viable DIY job. Given I presume you'll be edging the front of the stairs both for looks and durability this leads on to something simpler, already used to hide such joints anyway, and that's to use a strip of beading that simply covers the 'unsightly' joint. However I don't think you should assume your joints will be unsightly, and in fact you can make a point of ensuring they are nice and tight specifically so that you neither need to notch the riser or cover the joint with beading.

Comment: It seems that some folks here have figured out what you're asking, but it's not clear to me. If you could [edit] to include a picture or drawing of what you're after, that would help a lot. I _think_ I know, but, having just answered another question on another forum then edited it 3 times because the asker wasn't clear and I made the wrong presumptions, I'm hesitant to make a recommendation until I know what you're actually asking.

Comment: I admit, I don't really understand the goal, but as far as tools, you might try one of those "oscillating cutters" (I don't even recall what they've named those...) run along a straightedge. I've done that, and it works with a steady hand to cut a groove or rabbet/dado kind of channel...It's slow work. Doing a whole staircase would make for a crappy afternoon.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and comments. The first option as one you suggested is to just cut neatly and fit tightly, however since most materials have movements during different temperatures it may leave a gap during cold times and may warp slightly in hotter temperatures, however, on a step its only a difference of millimetres. Most people cut it just to fit and run a colour coded silicone around it, hardly noticeable. The second option is to use an oscillating tool or "multitool" and notch it carefully with a straight edge, laborious and time-consuming, but not everythings easy :)

Comment: Beading is the other suggestion from one of you, it's an option but I feel too time-consuming and no beadings available to exactly match the laminate flooring. As for stair nosing or bull nosing, they normally sell with the flooring but none available, so I am going for architectural stainless, purposefully folded to fit the front edge.

Comment: Thanks again for your input guys

Comment: *"since most materials have movements during different temperatures"* You're dealing with two known materials — solid wood and laminate — neither of which change dimension with changes in temperature. You're thinking of humidity. And at the dimensions one is dealing with on a stair you can ignore this entirely. With the existing parts of the stair you'd only be dealing with a change in the **thickness* of the riser, which is vanishingly small (perhaps 0.1mm, impossible to see when standing). And the laminate flooring, in common with most manmade board materials, should be dimensionally stable.

Comment: True, they are dimensionally stable but still hydrostatic, have minor movements, hardly noticeable I think. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no power tool technique that I can envisage that will allow this to be done in situ.

Since you used the tags for router and circular saw specifically, there just isn't the required access. Even if you could start the process with either in the middle perhaps, both the wall and handrail sides of the staircase and the body of the tool itself — very much so in the case of a circular saw! — are (as far as I can see, insurmountable) obstacles to extending it to both edges as needed.

This leads on to the thought of using hand tools, while there are some methods that suggest themselves as I indicate in my Comment I don't think this is a viable option for the typical homeowner<sup>1</sup>. I think only an experienced carpenter or woodworker is in a position to even attempt this, with or without one or two useful-but-not-essential specialist tools<sup>2</sup>, since you basically have one shot to get it right every time.

Leading on from the hand-tool methods I think it's theoretically possible to use other power tools to do similar work, specifically an oscillating tool and a power chisel, but neither should be used for detail work by a first-time user and this isn't a job where you can train yourself in on them as you go (since the first one pretty much has to be as perfect as all of the rest of them).

So I think this leaves as options the following:

- hide the joint with beading;
- ensure the joint between laminate and riser is tight enough<sup>3</sup> that you're happy with how it looks after installation.

Both are fairly simple to implement and IMO aesthetically acceptable but your mileage may vary.

---

<sup>1</sup> Without the required tools and experience using them — the cost is somewhat prohibitive but the learning curves (e.g. for sharpening) are unquestionably too steep.

<sup>2</sup> E.g. a floorboard saw or *azebiki* and a cranked-neck chisel.

<sup>3</sup> By undercutting by just a few degrees so the top edge is sure to register against the riser, *and* by scribing if necessary.

Comment: Hi Graphus . this is what I am going with, there are some pretty good blades available nowadays to use with a multitool or the oscillating saw, I will use a straight edge to guide me along, the good thing with an oscillating tool is, it's not going to kick back or run-ff " on me and make a mess :) Probably take me all day - that's my Sunday ruined, but what the heck. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Well if you are going with an oscillating tool for doing the top edge of the notch best of luck! But how are you going to remove the bulk of the material? As I said in the original wording of my first Comment before I revised it, this is theoretically possible but you'll hate yourself for taking it on ^_^